# Height of div element not matching parent's height when 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a bootstrap layout with two panels with a navbar and a sticky footer.

I want my sidebar to have a background color that goes all the way down. But when my right panel has more content, my left panel's background color does not go all the way to the bottom. I have my navbar and container placed inside a div tag and the container contains the right and left panel. I want the right and left panel to scroll together and do not want them to have their separate scroll bars. My code looks like this:

```
body, html, .row-offcanvas {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 290px;
    max-width: 220px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#main {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amirshadaab/ouqda63m/

When m sidebar has a height of 100%, it does not take the height of the parent container but stops in the middle and when I get rid of the height: 100% from sidebar, my background for the side panel is only going till the content ends and not all the way down. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `min-height: 100%;`? - http://jsfiddle.net/L7rrmyfw/

Comment: min-height:100% does the same thing as height:100%. It does not take the background color all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/w6zppc65/

Comment: Thanks Mary!! Exactly what I needed. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: but you need to add fixed width to `#sidebar` (e.g. 290px) in my solution instead of `min-width: 290px;` and `max-width: 220px;`, see here - http://jsfiddle.net/bw1yksbb/

Comment: @Mary Melody Can you please help me with getting the collapsible panel working with IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as supposed to, since your wrapper `row-offcanvas` is 100% in height and **scrollable**. Sidebar takes the same height, but is not scrollable. That's why it "ends" before you reach it's end.

Remove `height: 100%` and it works.

Comment: The background does not go all the way to the bottom. How do I make it go all the way down to the bottom to fill the wrapper?

Comment: @StreetSoldier use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%`

Comment: So I got rid of the height: 100% from sidebar and replaced it with min-height: 100%. It still does the same thing.

Comment: Does the background color on sidebar go all the way to the bottom of the page and not just the content?

Comment: @StreetSoldier Okay, my fault. It's not filled completly, you need to add a wrapper inside of `row-offcanvas`, containing `sidebar` and `main`, then the `sidebar` should stretch on the same height as `main`, since it's wrapper is height 100% and not scrollable.

Comment: I don't know why it still won't work. Isn't row-offcanvas already a wrapper? Why does it need another wrapper? Can you fork the jsfiddle please?